# I have Golden Gate on oracle 12c. Is it possible to get subset of data (like Where condition) from source to replicate

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I have Golden Gate on oracle 12c. Is it possible to get subset of data (like Where condition) from source to replicate in the target database.

Second question: Is it possible to replicate data using golden gate in to two different databases if so how. From one source to two target schemas.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, it is possible to get subset of data. Use the:

   - FILTER
   - WHERE

clause at the Extract or the Replicat param file.

2. Yes, it is possible to replicate to two targets. There are two possibilities:

   - You just can one Extract process and two Replicat processes (which are reading one trail),
   - You can create two Extract processes writing data to two trail files and two Replicat processes.

Each one of the Replicat processes would be writing data to a separate database target.

Comment: Thank you Adam. Is it possible to join multiple tables in where clause?

Comment: Replication is replicating changes in tables not SQL queries. Every DML operation (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) is associated always with one table. What do you mean joins? Can you please give an examples of JOIN insert that you want to replicate?